# React Native Animation Boomerang style

Tags: react-native

I am trying to create a red led "Recording Like" element. I'd like to see it blinking smoothly.

```
useEffect(() => {
Animated.loop(
  Animated.timing(
    fadeAnim,
    {
      toValue: 0,
      duration: 1000
      
    }
  ).start(() =>{
    Animated.timing(
      fadeAnim,
      {
        toValue: 1,
        duration: 1000
      }
    ).start(); 
  })
).start();
}, [fadeAnim])

 <Animated.View style={[styles.recordingLed, {opacity: fadeAnim}]} />
```

It actually goes to 0, then to 1 and then stop. I need something continuos, endless. Any clue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add some `Easing` (https://reactnative.dev/docs/easing) to your animation run smoothly, example:

```js
const fadeAnim = new Animated.Value(0);

useEffect(() => {
Animated.loop(
  Animated.timing(fadeAnim, {
     toValue: 1,
     duration: 1000,
     easing: Easing.bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1.0),
     useNativeDriver: true,
   }),
).start();
}, [fadeAnim]);

<Animated.View style={[styles.recordingLed, {opacity: fadeAnim}]} />
```

Also you can check this:
Maybe some pre made animations from can help you https://github.com/oblador/react-native-animatable#animations-2 ? Remember to mark the `looping` flag (https://github.com/oblador/react-native-animatable#looping)